# ¿Con angular puedo modificar un archivo alojado en un servidor? O tengo que implementar algo extra?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nodejs

En si lo que quiero es modificar las lineas de un archivo en el servidor.

Uso Nodejs del lado del Back-end

Answer (score 1):

Si utilizas AngularJS para renderizar del lado del servidor lo podrías hacer directamente. Pero en la mayoría de los casos angular se utiliza netamente en frontend así que necesitarás algún método remoto (RESTFul) en el backend que ejecute tu acción sobre el archivo.

Mi recomendación  es la acción ejecutarla con angular a través de un método remoto y en el backend manejar la edición del archivo.

Cómo usas Nodejs del lado del servidor tienes que hacer el método remoto ya sea con express o el framework que uses para la interfaz RESTFul y utilizar el módulo nativo de node js 'fs' para crear tu clase o función con este feat.

```
var fs=require('fs');

fs.writeFile('./archivo1.txt','línea 1\nLínea 2',function(error){
    if (error)
        console.log(error);
    else
       console.log('El archivo fue creado');
});

console.log('última línea del programa');
```